# Differences between $.replaceWith() and $.remove + $.appendTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experiencing different results when I use these two bits of code. To me, they should be equivalent. What is the difference?

```
var mapString = '<map id="map"><area shape="poly" coords="52,21,92,21,92,196,52,196"></map>';

//  First option:
$('#map').replaceWith(mapString);

//  Second option:
var mapParent = $('#map').parent();
$('#map').remove();
$(mapString ).appendTo(mapParent);
```

The first option replaces the existing map DOM element with a new map element represented as a string. The second option removes the existing map DOM element and then appends a new map element.

Shouldn't these be the same...? It appears that my map's area doesn't refresh when calling replaceWith.

EDIT: Does the first not cause a browser repaint where the second one does?

Comment: The result should be the same. Perhaps browser doesn't repaint the window.

Comment: That is what I'm thinking, as well.

Comment: `replaceWith` effectively does this: `$('#map')[0].parentNode.replaceChild(newMap);` which is definitely very close to the second option, except it doesn't explicitly remove the old content first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not the same since:

- **replaceWith()**: the replaced element will be on the same position (f.e. second child of its parent)
- **appentTo()**: the appended element will be the last child of its parent!

Comment: Ahh yeah, this is a difference, too. Any idea on if one causes a repaint and the other does not?

Comment: Normally this should cause a repaint, if it does not for any reason try something like this: https://coderwall.com/p/ahazha/force-redraw-on-an-element-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have other script errors on your page? This code sample works for me in both cases:

```js
var newContent = '<div id="original">New Content!</div>';

$('#original').replaceWith(newContent);


var parent = $('#original2').parent();
$('#original2').remove();
$(newContent).appendTo(parent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="original">Original Content 1</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="original2">Original Content 2</div>
</div>
```